# Javascript variable loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, google-maps-markers

I need to assign 50 map markers for a google map. I don't want to have the (almost) same line of code 50 times. What is the best way to loop through this easily and optimize code?

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(location1_latitude,location1_longitude),map: map1,title:location1});

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(location2_latitude,location2_longitude),map: map1,title:location2});

var marker3 = ...
```

repeating to

```
var marker50 = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(location50_latitude,location50_longitude),map: map1,title:location50});
```

Comment: Use arrays, search about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two arrays and iterate over them:

```
var location_latitude = [0,1,2,3,4,5] // all your latitudes
var location_longitude = [0,1,2,3,4,5] // all your longitudes
var location_titles = ['loc0','loc1','loc2','loc3','loc4','loc5']
var markers = []

for (var i = 0; i < location_latitude.length && i < location_longitude.length && i < location_titles.length; i++) {
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(location_latitude[i],location_longitude[0]),map: map1,title:location_titles[i]});
}
```

you can also abstract lat, lng and title into an object:

```
var locations = [{lat: 0, lng: 0, title: 'latlng0'},{lat: 0, lng: 0, title: 'latlng0'}] // depending on how you get you're data, you'll want to adjust your loop's format so you don't have to manually convert it
var markers = []

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var current = locations[i]
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(current.lat,current.lng),map: map1,title:current.title});
}
```